# Drupal: Display exposed filter value in view title

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I'm using Drupal 6 with the Views module.

I have a view with an exposed filter, I'd like to display the user selected value of that filter in the title of the view. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to use jQuery to change detect a change in the select list and set the selected value as the title of your view.